# What is ./ in BASH

Tags: command-line, bash

I was playing around in a shell and typed ./. I go the following output:

```
bash: ./: Is a directory
```

It looks like "./" checks if a directory with the given name exist. I was trying to find documentation on this to see if my understanding was right, but can't find anything online. Can anyone explain this one to me?

Comment: Nope. `./` is the same as `.`, which is the current directory. And not just in Linux or just in the bash shell.

Comment: Well, I feel like an idiot. Thanks for the answers though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A general definition for this is likely not to be found in the Bash manual, but [the POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap04.html#tag_04_11) (section Pathname Resolution):

> The special filename dot shall refer to the directory specified by its predecessor.

Well, what is the predecessor if we only have `.`? I emphasized the important part:

> If the pathname does not begin with a slash, the predecessor of the first filename of the pathname shall be taken to be **the current working directory** of the process

Also,

> A pathname that contains at least one non-slash character and that ends with one or more trailing slashes shall be resolved as if a single dot character ( '.' ) were appended to the pathname

So, when you type `./` it is resolved as `./.`, which basically points to your current working directory. When you type something in your shell and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the shell will try to execute the first part as a command. (Basically the first bunch of characters up until the first whitespace.)

There is no command or executable file called `./.`, so it will fail and tell you that `./` "is a directory". Interestingly, `.` *is* a command (it's a builtin also found as `source`), so when you just type `.` you'll get: `bash: .: filename argument required`.

Comment: By the way, the proper way to check if a directory exists is `test -d /path/to/dir`

Answer (score 3):

As others have written, `./` is the name of the current directory. When you typed `./` at the bash prompt and hit Enter, you attempted to execute the current directory as a command, which of course failed, and bash gave you the message (paraphrased), "I can't do that. `./` is a directory and I can't execute directories as commands."

Answer (score 2):

The `.` implies the current directory. You use `./` as prefix for any files in the current directory.

Similarly, `..` implies the previous (higher) directory. It is often used when going to a higher level directory, e.g. `cd ../../../`

Given a filesystem with the contents:

```
# Comments start with a hash and aren't parsed
/                    # root directory
/foo/                # first level directory
/foo/bar/            # second level directory
/foo/bar/baz         # third level directory
/foo/bar/baz/qux     # a file in the third level directory
```

If you're in the third level director (baz), and you run `ls`, you'll see `qux`. If you run `ls .`, you get the same ouput, as well as if you run `ls ./`.

If you're in the third level director (baz), and you run `ls ..` and `ls ../` both give you `baz`. That is, the contents of the directory one level higher.

Comment: Incorrect – the current directory is never in the PATH. Otherwise that'd be a huge security issue.

Comment: My bad, you're right. So then why don't you have to preface the directory after `cd`  with `./`?

Comment: PATH only applies to executables. When you type `foo`, the shell tries to find an executable called `foo` in your PATH, and it'll run the first `foo` it found. If you enter `cd bar`, `bar` is simply an option passed to `cd`, which will by default look in the current directory for possible directories to `cd` to.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux ./ means the current directory ( and ../ refers to the parent directory).

If you do an ls -a you will see . and .. listed as directories  (you need the -a because . represents a hidden directory)